# The connectedness of $SO(3, \mathbb R)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

There is an exercise on page 114 of Humphreys' *Linear Algebraic Groups* (GTM 21)

> Prove that $SO(3, \mathbb R)$ (= group of $3 \times 3$ real orthogonal matrices of determinate $1$) is a connected subgroup of $SL(3, \mathbb C)$ consisting of semisimple elements, but not commutative.

The semisimplicity of the elements and the noncommutativity of the group is clear. For the connectedness, I think this proposition might be applied:

> Let $G$ be an algebraic group, $I$ an idex set, $f_i: X_i \rightarrow G$ $(i \in I)$ a family of morphisms from irreducible varieties $X_i$, such that $e \in Y_i = f_i(X_i)$ for each $i \in I$. Set $M = \cup_{i \in I} Y_i$. Then the intersection of all closed subgroup of $G$ containing $M$ is a connected subgroup of $G$.

But I don't know how to determine the $X_i$'s.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Hint: the group $SO(3)$ acts transitively on the set of positively oriented orthonormal bases of $\Bbb R^3$.

Comment: @Andrea Mori: Thank you very much for the hint. I am sorry but I don't know how is this fact related to the connectedness of the group. May I ask for some further hint? Thanks again.

Comment: @ShiniaSakai: well, let $g\in SO(3)$ and let $\cal B$ the orthonormal basis of $\Bbb R^3$ obtained applying $g$ to the standard one. If you manage to obtain the basis $\cal B$ from the standard one by moving the latter continuously so that at each "time" $t$ the basis stays orthonormal, this amounts to finding a path in $SO(3)$ joining the identity to $g$, i.e. showing that $SO(3)$ is pathwise connected. It shouldn't be too hard to visualize it

Comment: (continued) (move the first standard vector to the first vector in $\cal B$ moving along the sphere $S^2$ and drag the other two vectors along keeping them on the orthogonal plane and at a right angle. When the first vector is in place, rotate the other two into the correct position. This works because $SO(3)$ kees the orientation)

Comment: @Andrea Mori: Thank you very much for the geometric answer~ Thanks a lot for taking time to explain it to me.